# 'Column name not valid' error in sqlce update command, using webmatrix 3.0

Tags: razor, webmatrix

I am attempting to make a simple web application with WebMatrix 3.0 using cshtml and sqlce.

The table "person" includes these columns (the first is a primary key and identity, the other two permit NULL values):

```
ID
firstmi
last
```

I am attempting to make a simple form to update the "firstmi" and "last" fields in the row where ID = id.

When the page loads, I set `var id=Request["id"]`.  Variables "personFirstMI" and "personLast" are set to the values of two respective textboxes.

When the following code is run:

```
db.Execute("UPDATE person SET firstmi=personFirstMI, last=personLast WHERE ID=id");
```

The following error results:

> The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = ,Column name = personFirstMI ]

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I don't understand what "node name" refers to. And I don't understand why the column name in my SQL syntax would be read as "personFirstMI" rather than "firstmi."  If I attempt to SET "firstmi" equal to "personFirstMI" WHERE "ID" equals "id", then my understanding is that this should result in the "firstmi" field in the "ID" row being set equal to "personFirstMI".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use parameter markers in the form @0, @1, @2, @3 and so on, incrementing by one each time, in your SQL and then pass the values in to the Execute method:

```
var sql = "UPDATE person SET firstMi = @0, last = @1 WHERE ID = @2";
db.Execute(sql, personFirstMI, personLast, id);
```

See this tutorial for more on working with data in ASP.NET Web Pages: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/5-working-with-data

Comment: Wow. Thank you. I tried about 50 variations of parameters and variables simply because I didn't understand that they're incremented in the order listed in the Execute command (I thought they were listed in the order that I requested them from the form that they were submitted from).